# In Excel VBA 2010: How to destroy excel vba.application object

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel.Application object which seems to live on as a Windows Process AFTER my VBA code has executed and Excel 2010 is completely closed out.
i.e. Windows Task Manager shows the Process as "EXCEL.EXE *32", even after I've closed Excel.

Here's some code below :

Public Sub Test
   Dim xls As Object

```
Set xls = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = xls.Workbooks.Add

fullFilePath = importFolderPath & "\" & "A1"
wb.SaveAs fullFilePath, AccessMode:=xlExclusive    ' SAVE WORKBOOK AND CLOSE !
wb.Close (True)

' question: How can I destroy the xls object ????
```

end sub

Basically I can't figure out how to destroy the "xls" I've created in my code. And as I've stated above, it causes EXCEL.EXE *32 to live on as a windows process.

thanks in advance....
Bob

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `xls.Quit` after you close the workbook

Comment: Thanks ! I looked for Destroy, Exit, Close...all except the obvious QUIT. Thank you so much.

Comment: it's also prompting me to overwrite the prev excel file on this line of code: wb.SaveAs fullFilePath, AccessMode:=xlExclusive  . I've tried to turn off alerts but this line doesn't work for this: Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Comment: Which version of Excel, just tried it with 2010 and it works for me